# Moving Data from SQL Server to Excel, Views or Query?

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2012

I have an Excel spreadsheet that pulls data from a view (that's pulling from another view) in SQL Server, this was created by someone other than myself. Due to recent changes in how we are storing data in SQL Server, the views no longer actively reflect the data needed.

The current Excel spreadsheet use a command to simply pull the rows from the view, would it make more sense to simply use a query to gather the data from the necessary tables? Is there any advantages to using the views over a regular query?

There is no security being enforced in regards to the view as well, the connection is using an admin user.

Comment: *"that pulls data from a view (that's pulling from another view)"*  FYI, nested views tends to perform poorly. if you are redesigning your views, then you're better off not nesting them.

Comment: When we talk about regular views, the only advantage over query is that I see a shorter expression, i.e. 'select * from view' will be easier to type and edit in MS Query than 'select * from ... join ... join ... where ...' etc. If we are talking about indexed views, then they can greatly improve performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk about regular views, the only advantage over query is that I see a shorter expression, i.e. 'select * from view' will be easier to type and edit in MS Query than 'select * from ... join ... join ... where ...' etc. If we are talking about indexed views, then they can greatly improve performance